# Integer overflow in Fibonacci number

Tags: fibonacci, integer-overflow

**I was solving this codechef problem on Fibonacci numbers. It says number is of 1000 digits then why it is not causing integer overflow in tester's solution when it is scanning the array and storing it in unsigned long long int. I can't understand how solution is working. Below is the problem and tester's solution.**

```
The Head Chef has been playing with Fibonacci numbers for long . He has learnt several tricks related to Fibonacci numbers . Now he wants to test his chefs in the skills . 

A fibonacci number is defined by the recurrence :

f(n) = f(n-1) + f(n-2) for n > 2 
and f(1) = 0 
and f(2) = 1 . 

Given a number A , determine if it is a fibonacci number.
Input

The first line of the input contains an integer T denoting the number of test cases. The description of T test cases follows.
The only line of each test case contains a single integer A denoting the number to be checked .
Output

For each test case, output a single line containing "YES" if the given number is a fibonacci number , otherwise output a single line containing "NO" .
Constraints

1 ≤ T ≤ 1000
1 ≤ number of digits in A ≤ 1000
The sum of number of digits in A in all test cases <= 10000.
Example

Input:
3
3
4
5

Output:
YES
NO
YES


**Tester's solution:**
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <algorithm>
#include <set>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;
int const mx = 6666;
set <unsigned long long> f;
unsigned long long fib[mx + 10];
char s[mx + 1];
int main(){
//  freopen("input.txt", "r", stdin);
//  freopen("output.txt", "w", stdout);
    fib[0] = 0;
    fib[1] = 1;
    f.insert(1);
    f.insert(0);
    int i;
    for (i = 2; i <= mx; i++){
        fib[i] = fib[i - 1] + fib[i - 2];
        f.insert(fib[i]);
    }
    int tc;
    cin>>tc;
    while (tc--){
        unsigned long long n = 0, ten = 10;
        cin>>s;
        int len = strlen(s);
        for (i = 0; i < len; i++){
            char q = s[i];
            unsigned long long a = q - '0';
            n = n * ten + a;
        }
        if (f.find(n) == f.end()) printf("NO\n");
        else printf("YES\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From [cplusplus](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/climits/) you will see that,

`ULLONG_MAX` Maximum value for an object of type `unsigned long long int` is    **18446744073709551615 (2<sup>64</sup>-1)** or greater.

> The actual value depends on the particular system and library implementation, but shall reflect the limits of these types in
>   the target platform.

Above information is just to let you know its a BIG number. Moreover the cause of not getting overflow is not the limit i mentioned.

#### Most probably, the input file of judge does not contain any input that can cause an overflow.

And its still possible to set such input even after fulfilling the conditions,

```
1 ≤ T ≤ 1000
1 ≤ number of digits in A ≤ 1000
The sum of number of digits in A in all test cases <= 10000.
```